# How to prove that the inverse exists on the whole space X?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I was reading Kreyszig's book on functional analysis when I came across this theorem:

"Let $T\in{}B(X,X)$, where $X$ is a Banach space. If $||T||<1$, then $(I-T)^{-1}$ exists as a bounded linear operator on the **whole** space $X$ and $(I-T)^{-1}= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}T^{i}=I+T+T^{2}+...$"

Here's my question:

The book proved this theorem by show that the series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}T^{i}$ converges absolutely, so that it is properly defined as an operator, and that $(I-T)(I+T+T^{2}+...T^{n}) \to I$ as $n\to\infty$.

But how can I prove that the operator $(I-T)$ is injective in the first place? And why can we say that $(I-T)^{-1}$ exists on the **whole** $X$ (which I believe would require the surjectivity of $(I-T)$ )?

Comment: You either $\sum$ or write $I+T+\ldots$. You don't sum over the infinite sum.

Comment: Sorry @AsafKaragila that was a typo.

Comment: A linear map is injective if and only if it has trivial kernel. So suppose there is some non-zero x with (I-T)x = 0. Then x = Tx so $||Tx||/||x|| \ge 1 \Rightarrow ||T|| \ge 1$, a contradiction.

Comment: @Conor Oh I see... Thank you! But what about the surjectivity?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint.

Let $\varphi :A\to B$ and $\psi:B\to A$ be maps between sets. Try to prove the following
$$
\psi\varphi=Id_A\Longrightarrow \psi \text{ is surjective and }\varphi\text{ is injective}
$$

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Vokram, not at all!${}{}{}$